# Ubuntu Gnome: Graphics error after boot and before login-screen

Tags: boot, drivers, gnome, graphics, amd-graphics

I have recently installed Ubuntu Gnome. An error occures after boot and before the login-screen. It looks like a wrong graphics configuration, but I just can't get behind the problem. When I login, everything works smoothly from then on.

```
$ lspci
```

lists me the following graphics card (I know it is old...)

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV710/M92 [Mobility Radeon HD 4330/4350/4550]
```

I am using the radeon driver. `$ dmesg` gives me a firmware error, I don't know if it's related to the problem.

```
[4.905633] [Firmware Bug]: Duplicate ACPI video bus devices for the same VGA controller, please try module parameter "video.allow_duplicates=1"if the current driver doesn't work.
```

I have added a config file in modprobe.d with no success of solving this bug. So maybe it is related to the graphics error?

I have had no issue with this graphics card in the past. This type of error only occurred yesterday for the first time when I booted the live USB. I thought "maybe it's just the live medium" and continued to install on my USB drive (I need the OS on a USB for my purposes, though I am only using it with this computer). The error occurs at the same time whenever I boot, so I think it is driver / settings related.

```
$ lshw -c video
```

Lists me, that I am using the radeon driver

```
description: VGA compatible controller
   product: RV710/M92 [Mobility Radeon HD 4330/4350/4550]
   vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: 00
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
   resources: irq:31 memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:de00(size=256) memory:f6df0000-f6dfffff memory:c0000-dffff
```

I am really thankful for any help that could lead to solving this issue.

I have already checked if it is related to splash screen, but it also appears after I dissabled it.

This is what it looks like. It always looks differently, sometimes "worse" sometimes "better". The login screen is normal (I can't attach another picture, since my reputation is not high enough)

#### Graphics error Picture 1

[image]

#### Graphics error Picture 2

[image]

Edit: 
I called the file "firmerror.conf" and this is what's inside:

```
video.allow_duplicates=1
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the name and content of the file that you added to `/etc/modprobe.d/`? Did you run `update-initramfs` before you rebooted? Thanks.

Comment: Hey, I am not aware of the fact that the initramfs would be affected by this. I read through a couple of articles  and the man page of modprobe.d and the way the bug asks for, it seems like it is a kernel module. I am not sure if or how I can load it to initramfs, the command `update-initramfs` doesn't work. I just ran `update-initramfs` and it was asking me for a parameter. I added -u thinking I'd update an existing initramfs.
`libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:635 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/firmerror.conf line 1: ignoring bad line starting with 'video.allow_duplicates=1' `

Comment: Well, there you go. That should have been `option [MODULE-NAME] video.allow_duplicates=1`. Then run `update-initramfs -u` in case the module is loaded before the root directory is mounted (see the other module configuration files and the manual page of `modprobe.d`). I don't know the module name though. You should find it in the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -A3 VGA`.